# How to navigate to a locally stored HTML file from another locally stored file? (More details given below)

Tags: javascript, android, html

I have two HTML files and their contents are:

file1.html

```
<body>
    <h1>
        THIS IS FILE1<br />
        <a href="./file2.html">GO TO FILE2</a>
    </h1>
</body>
```

file2.html

```
<body>
    <h1>
        THIS IS FILE2 <br />
        <a href="./file1.html">GO TO FILE1</a>
    </h1>
</body>
```

But when I click on the Link, it just shows ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND on chrome.

I tried to remove the "./" in the href tag, still won't work. 
How do I make this work? 
(The thing is I'm trying to make an attendance monitoring webpage, but our college location is such that celular internet is SHITTY for everyone, so hosting the files is not what I'm considering and trying to make this thing work in the phone storage itself. 
Any suggestions on this matter are welcome too :)

EDIT: Yes I have both the files in the same directory, just to make sure I even created a new directory just for these two files and still won't work

Comment: Where are they stored?  On the file system?  In assets?  Other?  Assets won't work, because they aren't actually on the filesystem so it can't do a relative link

Comment: @Gabe Sechan it's on the file system, specifically in internal storage/downloads on my OnePlus8T device.

Comment: You are not showing how you open the/a html file.

Answer (score 0):

file1 and file2 should be in the same directory (or change files path in code to the correct path)

Comment: Yes I have both the files in the same directory, just to make sure I even created a new directory just for these two files and still won't work

Comment: If you only invoke the file name it will work. Could you provide the HTTP that appears after clicking on those Achor tags?

Comment: I think the answer is a little clear now. The link that appears after I open file is content://media/external/file/1000033602 . Seems like chrome is doing it's own stuff before opening file

Comment: `appears after I open file is content://media/external/file/1000033602 .` No. Not after. You have that content scheme which you then use with ACTION_VIEW to open a browse.